# php mysql redirect image URL to link URL

Tags: php, mysql

some one use my image URL  in his site...
i want to redirect  my site image URL like this :

```
> mysite.com/wallpaper/image_car.jpg
```

redirect to

```
> mysite.com/wallpaper/image_car.html
```

when he use in his site then its redirect
i want code in php

Comment: Use some mod_rewrite perhaps? And complement it with a PHP page to handle where the redirection should go.

Comment: anton  .. i have no idea  how can i use in mod_rewrite ? please you will help me

Comment: the person website  use my bandwidth  . then i want image url convert to link url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yourdomain.com
RewriteRule ^\.jpg $1\.html [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all traffic not reffered by your domain witch ends with jpg to same URL which ends with html.

Place this snippet to .htaccess file or apache config file in appropriate location directive

Comment: in image SRC  they use my site images

Comment: That OK, they have something like this in src attribute : http://yourdomain.com/img/myimage.jpg. This code redirect them to http://yourdomain.com/img/myimage.html

Comment: This is exactly the way you want to do it. My answer is the same, but this is specifically what you need to do. +1.

Comment: if i use  yourdomain.com   to www.yourdomain.com  ?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yourdomain.com` is that you write

Comment: I know, but what you mean be "if i use yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com", please give full eample what you want to know ;)

Comment: 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yourdomain.com'  is that in code
i want like this 
'RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www.yourdomain.com'
 so thats is fine .. its will work or not  ?

Comment: Yes it should work for any domain you enter

Comment: for this which function is good in php?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the HTTP referrer header to see which domain is using your item, and redirect it if it's not you.

Comment: its many blogs sites use my images

Comment: I know, that's still the way to go. Look at @rkosegi's answer.